# How to generate AWS cloudfront signed url in apex?

Tags: scheduled-apex, aws

I am trying to generate AWS Cloudfront signed url using apex but every time get Access Denied.

public url is working fine. i.e.
jueh890044563.cloudfront.net/test.pdf

But I need a signed url of cloudfront.

**I have already done following things in AWS.**

S3 bucket is private.

test.pdf is private.

Created cloudfront Distribution (domain name is : jueh890044563.cloudfront.net)

**Apex code**

```
String keyPairId = 'YTEHJLKFHHRKF';

Datetime now = DateTime.now();

Datetime expireson = now.addDays(2);

Long Lexpires = expireson.getTime()/1000;

String policyStatement = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"jueh890044563.cloudfront.net/test.pdf","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":'+Lexpires+'}}}]}';

policyStatement = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policyStatement));


String privateKey = 'dfgdfgtgdfgdfgdfsgdfgdfsgdfgdfgdfgsdf'+

                    'dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgfgdfgdfsdf'+

                    'dfdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgfdgdfg/i0AB1Jz20QlGy'+

                    'dsfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdsfgdfgdfgffdfgdfg';

Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', blob.valueof(policyStatement),blob.valueof(privateKey)); 
String signed = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);


String downloadUrl = 'jueh890044563.cloudfront.net/test.pdf?Policy='+policyStatement+'&Signature='+signed+'&Key-Pair-Id='+keyPairId;
```

Is downloadUrl is signedUrl? When we run this url then return Access Denied.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've got mine working like so:

```
private HTTPResponse signURL(String endpoint) {
    String keyPairId = 'keyPairIdFromCF';
    String secret    = 'secretFromS3';
    String method    = 'GET';
    Datetime dt      = Datetime.now();
    Long longTime    = dt.getTime();
    Long expiryLong  = (longTime / 1000) + 3600;
    String expiry    = String.valueOf(expiryLong);
    String policy    = policy('http://' + cfhost + '/' + endpoint, expiry);
    String policyEnc = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(policy));
    String rPolicy   = cfReplace(policyEnc);
    Blob mac         = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1',
                                          Blob.valueOf(rPolicy),
                                          Blob.valueOf(secret));
    String signature = cfReplace(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac));

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod(method);
    req.setEndpoint('http://' + cfhost + '/' + endpoint + '?Policy=' +
        policyEnc + '&Signature=' + signature + '&Key-Pair-Id=' +
        keyPairId);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    return res;
}

private String policy(String url, String expTime) {
    return '{"Statement":[{"Resource":'+ url + ',"Condition":{' +
           '"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":'+ expTime + '}}}]}';
}

private String cfReplace(String s) {
    return s.replace('+', '-').replace('=', '_').replace('/', '~');
}
```

`cfhost` is obviously my Cloudfront domain. `cfReplace` is to change illegal characters as per the Cloudfront documentation. If you're still getting access denied, make sure your Cloudfront identity can both `getObjects` and `listBuckets`.